# Direct Link to a Quick Tab

Tags: blocks

Is there a way for me to create a direct link to a Quick Tab? I have a taxonony term page with two tabs one contains some view result and the other is specific page of site like quiz take url(node/23/take).

Comment: Are you using quicktab module? Then you may need to create link suffixed with `#quicktab-id`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find the link to load a tab, just hover over the tab and copy the link of that tab. You will notice that the link has an argument appended on the end that looks something like:

?qt-myquicktab=1#qt-quicktabs

```
      Note: The # sign and anything after that in the argument above is not actually required.
      You should change it to ?qt-myquicktab=1
```

This tells Quicktab to load the second tab (Quicktab starts counting at 0) in the third Quicktab block that you have created (a Quicktab ID of 3).

All you need to do is,place this URL argument on the end of any link that you want to load the alternative tab as the default and you are done.